# How to make .jar file portable with database?

Tags: jar, portability

i would like to make .jar application, which will be able to sava data without using any database (Postgres...) but i dont know, what type of datastorage i should use to make the application portable. I just want to .jar file, which is capable works on any cumputer with java installed. Is there some option? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always serialise Java objects to plain binary files. One file for each type of object to simulate a database table, or you can serialise all objects in the same file, but you need to know the order when you read them back.
Other solutions would be to serialise the java objects either as XML structures or JSON (using JAXB is very easy and strait forward to marshall/unmarshall) such structures.